# "head" only printing one line?

Tags: text-processing, grep, head

I've got a CSV file that's generated by saving as CSV from Excel. If I do "head" (or indeed "grep" or anything else) it only prints the first line:

```
head -n 10 messy.csv
10,15,11,21
```

But if I open the file in a text editor, or in Excel, it has many lines in it:

```
10,15,11,21
9,11,17,19
7,11,24,18
...
```

`head` works just fine on other files on the machine.

Why is this? (I suspect it's something to do with line endings, but I don't know what.) And how can I fix it?

Comment: Windows line endings in the CSV file?

Comment: Yes, wrong newlines, everything that comes from windows will have corrupted line breaks.

Comment: Files which come from Windows do not have *corrupted* line breaks as such –they have Windows line breaks.  When importing data with one OS's end-of-line style to another OS whose end-of-line style is different, it is just a simple cold fact that you need to cater for that (different) style in one way or another.

Answer (score 6):

I think it is line-ending related. Excel will save files with carriage return/line feed endings but `head` will be expecting line feeds only.

What output does this display:

`tr -d '\r' < messy.csv | head -10`

If it displays the 10 lines correctly, that's your answer.

`file` can tell you the line ending for certain text files (it will print *..., with CRLF line terminators*), but it doesn't do that for all text files (I believe it doesn't do it if it recognises the file as being something else, eg HTML).

Comment: Thanks. The `tr` outputs the whole file as one long string! `file messy.csv` prints  `messy.csv: ASCII English text, with CR line terminators`.

Comment: @Richard Very strange that your file only has carriage returns! Try `tr '\r' '\n' < messy.csv |head -10` then

Comment: This is almost certainly **not** a Windows issue. the behaviour described does not apply to a `\r\n` line ending.. It is probably an *Excel for Mac* issue –   *"Basically, saving a file as comma separated values (csv) uses a carriage return \r"* – see [Excel and line endings](http://nicercode.github.io/blog/2013-04-30-excel-and-line-endings/)

Comment: Mac systems use CR as line terminators. Fix the `tr` to swap CR for NL and it'll work.

Answer (score 5):

You have `\r` **only** as the end-of-line character for lines 2 onwards (up to line 10 at least). Line 1 has `\n` as the end-of-line character.   eg.

```
printf 'ABC\nXYZ\r123\r' | head
```

output (to the screen)

```
ABC
```

This is a *display* artifact related to terminal output. The `\r` kicks back to the start of the line and the next line overwrites it, and the last line gets overwritten –fully or partially– by the terminal prompt.

When the last `\r` delimited line is longer than the prompt, then that line is *partially* revealed (beyond the end of the prompt) – eg, In the following sampel output, the terminal prompt is just `nn $` (5 characters), where `nn` is the n'th command issued).

```
72 $ printf 'ABC\nXYZ\rabcdefghijklmnop\r' 
ABC
73 $ fghijklmnop
```

To fix it

```
sed -i.bak 's/\r$//; s/\r/\n/g' file
```

The `-i.bak` option causes the input `file` to be updated **i**nline and makes a backup `file.bak`. If you don't want a backup, just use `-i`.

Answer (score 2):

### Analyse your problem

`head` doesn't behave as you expect it.
Replace it by a simple analysis tool  `od` to see what is going on:

```
od -cx messy.csv
```

and then to see how `head` deal with this file:

```
head -2 messy.csv | od -cx
```

You will notice that `head` is dealing with the `\r` return ASCII code
(`0x0d`) as it was conceived for:

make the "carriage return" of original type writer. It does just bring back the current cursor position ready for the next position to write at "the beginning of line".

### Fix it

See the correct `sed` command here:
[fix '\r' from an Excel file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/213870/31707)

### For the record

This Microsoft bug is a winner one: this coding of Excel end of line is wrong for: Windows, Unix (all), MacOS X.

You can't outperform it :).

Answer (score -3):

I think the correct way is:

`head -10 file.txt` (to print starting 10 lines)

Another way can be:

`cat file.txt | head -10`

Comment: The `-n <count>` option is included in the [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/head.html) so most, if not all, `head` variants should support it.